# How to handle array formated JSON in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, json, swift, xcode, api

I'm trying to fetch latitude and longitude coordinates from this [API](https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?country=Sweden&city=Stockholm&street=odenplan&format=json) in Xcode. My problem is that the JSON file starts off as an array and therefore I'm not entirely sure how to access all the parts of it. Here is my function for it:

```
func FetchOriginCoordinates() {
        let locationUrl = URL(string: "https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?country=Sweden&city=Stockholm&street=odenplan&format=json")
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: locationUrl!) {data, response, error in
            if let data = data {

                if let decodedJson = try? JSONDecoder().decode([NominationStructure].self, from: data) {

                    self.originLat = String(decodedJson[0].lat)
                    self.originLon = String(decodedJson[0].lon)
                }
            }
        }.resume()
    }
```

I tried looking online on how to write the `struct` and this is what I found, but I doesn't work.

```
struct NominationStructure: Decodable {
    var lat: Float
    var lon: Float
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case lat = "lat"
        case lon = "lon"
    }
}
```

Comment: You are throwing away the error that will help you.  Get rid of the `try ?` and use `do/try/catch` - You can then `print(error)` in the `catch` block and `JSONDecoder` will tell you what is going wrong, which is that the values associated with the `lat` and `lon` keys are *strings*, not floats.  You will need to convert the values to floats yourself.

Comment: @Paulw11 Oh, I see. I will always use `catch` in the future from now on. Thanks for your help!